# Installation error BPM Suite JBoss: JBAS011639

Tags: jboss, oracle-bpm-suite

On installing, I recieved the following error

```
Script C:\Program Files\EAP10\cli-scripts\add-mdb-conf.cli failed to run.
CLI command failed: undefined
{
    "outcome" => "failed",
    "failure-description" => {"JBAS014671: Servicios fallidos" => {"jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.InVmConnectionFactory" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.messaging.default.jms.connection-factory.InVmConnectionFactory: JBAS011639: No logró crear connection-factory
    Caused by: HornetQException[errorType=ILLEGAL_STATE message=HQ129005: Connector 'in-vm' not found on the main configuration file]"}},
    "rolled-back" => true,
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "restart-required"},
    "command" => undefined
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Please help me with this error!

Datos:
BPM SUITE 6.3.0 GA //
EAP 6.4.0 //
jdk1.8.0_101

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install BPM Suite 6.3 in EAP 6.4.0 you have to update your EAP first. BPM Suite 6.3 will not be installed properly on any EAP version smaller than 6.4.4 . Download an update for EAP 6.4 (EAP-6.4.4 or greater patch), apply the patch to the server and then try again the installation. Another option, is to use smaller version of BPM Suite (BPM Suite 6.2 for example), but i don't recommend it as solution.